# creating pandas datetime index from list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a very large list with tuples as:

```
multiIdx[1:4]
[(2017, 1, 1, 2), (2020, 1, 1, 3), (2019, 1, 1, 4)]
```

where the tuple elements are (year, month, day, hour)

I want to create `datetime` or `pandas datetimeindex` from that list of tuples. Currently I am using `list comprehension`. Is there a more pythonic way to achieve the above.

Comment: Provide more details on your input and expected output (as it should be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`pd.to_datetime`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) can take as an argument a [**`pd.DataFrame`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) with appropriately named columns.  the [**`pd.DataFrame`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor will appropriately parse a list of tuples.  All that is left for us to do is assign the correct column names and pass to [**`pd.to_datetime`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(multIdx, columns=['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']))

0   2017-01-01 02:00:00
1   2020-01-01 03:00:00
2   2019-01-01 04:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small remark to the answer.
If the multi-index variable (in this case `multIdx`) is in fact a MultiIndex variable type, the MultiIndex variable should be transformed to a list.
An example using the solution provided by @piRSquared would be:

```py
# When
# type(multIdx) yields to something like:

# MultiIndex([(2017, 1, 1, 2), 
#             (2020, 1, 1, 3), 
#             (2019, 1, 1, 4)], 
#             names=['year', 'month', 'day']

# Then the variable should be converted to a list
new_multIdx = list(multIdx)

# The working code would be
pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(new_multIdx, columns=['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']))
```